# SQL server define local variable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following query in SQL Server

```
SELECT name,id FROM [someDatabase] 
where id like 'testName'
```

Now I want to use name and id in another query and define name as NAME and id as ID

```
SELECT DISTINCT vision FROM [someDatabase] WHERE name = NAME 

And id = ID
```

I'm not familiar with SQL server syntax. How do I define these two as local variables?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare variables to hold the data first:

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(100),
        @id   INT
```

Then you can assign to these variables in your select statement.  Note that this query will not produce any output.

```
SELECT @name = name,@id = id FROM [someDatabase] 
where id like 'testName'
```

Finally you can use these values in your query

```
SELECT DISTINCT vision FROM [someDatabase] WHERE name = @name 
And id = @id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT vision FROM [somedatabase] 
WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM [someDatabase] where id like 'testName')
AND id IN (SELECT id FROM [someDatabase] WHERE id LIKE 'testName')
```

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: True but it should give the result he is after presupposing that the IDs are unique and LIKE 'testname' only produces one ID.

Comment: Why hit the same table 3 times when once will do it? Why bother using like with no wildcards?

Comment: Is it the same table? I thought he was querying the "vision" column from table_2 based on the id and name resulting from a query to a table_1, he doesn't exactly say. I was using LIKE because anders did in his question so I assume he needs the facility for a boolean variable here...?